# View shifted across to the right

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out why this `tableView` is shifted across to the right, it appears in every view the app uses, yet the app itself displays fine, it's only when the `tableView` appears is everything shifted out of the screen.

I believe the initializing is here;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Lets load the frame");

   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view setFrame: frame];

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

    m_mywork = nil;

    dataArray = [LoadSessionController loadTableData:YES];
}
```

[image]

Here is the initializing from another class;

on iPad display is perfect.

```
- (void) ShowInitialMenu
{
    InitialMenuController *MewMgrController = [[InitialMenuController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    MewMgrController.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: MewMgrController];
    if(![ColorSplashAppDelegate isiPad]){
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
        popover.delegate = self;
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(30.0, 940.0, 30.0, 480.0)
                                 inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                               animated:YES];
        ColorSplashAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        appDelegate.popoverController = popover;
    }

    [navController release];
    [MewMgrController release];

    [self enableUserAction:YES];
}
```

Comment: why did you set self.view frame ?

Comment: add leading, trailing , top and bottom constraints with zero value .

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the frame of `self.view` in a view controller.

Comment: give more relevant details!

Comment: from where are you calling ShowInitialMenu()?

Comment: From the main app ViewController.mm 

`[self performSelector:@selector(ShowInitialMenu) withObject:nil afterDelay :0.0f];`

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view setFrame: frame];

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

    m_mywork = nil;

}
```

Comment: Did not work, but I have added extra info to the bottom of original question